# Proving a prime $p$ divides $n$ if and only if $p^2$ divides $n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility

> Suppose $p$ is a prime, and $n$ is an integer. Prove that $p$ divides $n$ if and only if $p^2$ divides $n^2$.

How do I prove this statement?

Comment: Well, if $p |n$, then it is obvious that $p^2 | n^2$.  For the other way, use the following result: If $p$ is a prime dividing a product $ab$ , then $p$ divides $a$ or $p$ divides $b$.

Comment: Yeah, if p divides n it is obvious that p^2 divides n^2. I'm stuck at proving that p divides n^2 (because p*p divides n*n, it must be that single p divides n^2).

Comment: You have to use the fact that p is prime, and probably think a bit about unique prime factorisations.

Comment: @ConMan This does not require $p$ to be prime.  All rational square roots of integers are themselves integers, so it's true for all non-zero integers $p$ (and somewhat vacuously true for $p=0$).

Comment: Good point, although it's probably easier knowing that p is prime because then you just have to look at a single prime factor.

Comment: I think that I got the answer. Thank you